# Overload resolution of virtual methods

Tags: c#, methods, virtual, overloading

Consider the code

```cs
public class Base
{
   public virtual int Add(int a,int b)
   {
      return a+b;
   }
}

public class Derived:Base
{
   public override int Add(int a,int b)
   {
      return a+b;
   }

   public int Add(float a,float b)
   {
      return (Int32)(a + b);
   }
}
```

If I create an instance of Derived class and call Add with parameters of type int why it is calling the Add method with float parameters

```cs
Derived obj =new Derived()
obj.Add(3,5)

// why this is calling 
Add(float a,float b)
```

Why it is not calling the more specific method?

Comment: How do you know that 3 and 5 are int? Try specifying their types and see what happens.

Comment: Are you able to compile this? You may get some cast errors like float to int?

Comment: This doesn't compile as there's no implicit conversion from float to int. Are you sure the second Add method returns int?

Comment: @Ritch ,@Matthew ..It doesn't make any difference even if u add something like this `int a =3;int b=5;obj.Add(a,b);`

Comment: Also read the following post by John Skeet.</br>
[http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is by design. Section 7.5.3 of the C# language specification states:

> For example, the set of candidates for a method invocation does not include methods marked override (§7.4), and methods in a base class are not candidates if any method in a derived class is applicable (§7.6.5.1).

In other words, because your `Derived` class has a non-overridden `Add` method, the `Add` method in the `Base` class (and its overridden version in `Derived`) are no longer candidates for overload resolution.

Even though `Base.Add(int,int)` would be a better match, the existance of `Derived.Add(float,float)` means that the base class method is never even considered by the compiler.

Eric Lippert discusses some of the reasons for this design in [this blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/future-breaking-changes-part-three).

Comment: +1 good answer. Proof, explanation and links for further reading.

Comment: Is there any way to add an overload for a virtual method while keeping the original method visible as well?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/teasers-answers.html

when choosing an overload, if there are any compatible methods declared in a derived class, all signatures declared in the base class are ignored - even if they're overridden in the same derived class!