# Why is a worse overload picked if a better one exists but is virtual?

Tags: c#, methods, overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Overload resolution of virtual methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789783/overload-resolution-of-virtual-methods)

Let suppose I make 2 methods.

```
class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {

        DerivedClass d = new DerivedClass();
        int i = 10;
        d.DoAThing(i);

    }
}
```

**BasClass**

```
class BaseClass
{

    public virtual void DoAThing(int x)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Base.DoAThing(int)");
    }
}
```

**DerivedClass**

```
class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{

    public override void DoAThing(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived.DoAThing(int)");
    }

    public void DoAThing(object o)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived.DoAThing(object)");

    }
}
```

When I run the application, `Derived.DoAThing(object)` was printed out on the console.
 Can anyone explain, what is the preference, why `DoAThing(object o)` function were called instead of overridden one, as overridden function's syntax better fits calling expression.

Also  if I remove **override** keyword

Then out put is

**the output is Derived.DoAThing(int).**

Why is it?

Comment: isnt the order of these things first: own methods second overridden methods last baseclass methods, when compiler/linker is looking for the method.?? just a hunch...

Comment: Your edit to your question is also answered by the duplicate link. Please read it.